# Two clicks are needed to fire an action in react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have created a popover with some options to choose the number of rows in a data table using reactstrap popover. the code goes as following :

```
       <OverlayTrigger
                                trigger="click"
                                rootClose
                                placement='bottom'
                                overlay={
                                    <Popover className="popover-contained" >
                                        <Popover.Content className="popover-content">
                                            {numberOfLinesoptions.map(numberOfLinesoption =>
                                                <div className="option-wrapper" >
                                                    <img src={isLimit === numberOfLinesoption ? blueCircle : blackCircle} />
                                                    <a className={isLimit === numberOfLinesoption ? 'selected' : ''} onClick={() => getLines(numberOfLinesoption)}
                                                    >{numberOfLinesoption} Rows</a>
                                                </div>
                                            )}
                                        </Popover.Content>
                                    </Popover>
                                }
                            >
                                <Dropdown className="btn-group">
                                    <Dropdown.Toggle >
                                        {isLimit} Rows
                                    </Dropdown.Toggle>
                                </Dropdown>
                            </OverlayTrigger>
```

And, here is the function getLines and the array of lines numbers:

```
 function getLines(num) {
        setLimit(num);
        dispatch(loadFetchedData(isLimit)
    }
```

And, here is also the array of rows numbers :

```
    const numberOfLinesoptions = ["10", "15", "20"];
```

As you can see, I want to click on the one option in the popover and then, gets a certain number of rows accordingly. What happens here is that I have to click twice on the option to call the function getLines and change the value of isLimit (The initial number of pages) as well. So why does this happen and how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the full component? If you have a state variable like `const [isLimit, setLimit] = useState()`, then one issue I can see is `loadFetchedData` will always use the old state value, since setter functions are asynchronous. It's hard to suggest much more without the full code.

Answer (score 1):

State updates are async. You are setting the state `setLimit(num)` and in the next line you are trying to access the latest value `dispatch(loadFetchedData(isLimit))`. However, `isLimit` will still have previous value.

**Solution** - You can simply pass `num` to `loadFetchedData` instead of `isLlimit`

```js
function getLines(num) {
  setLimit(num);
  dispatch(loadFetchedData(num));
}
```

Comment: hi - is it working...any questions let me know ... thanks..